# Is the conditional density function a function of two variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, density-function

I believe I'm having trouble interpreting the definition of a conditional density function. The definition from Wikipedia states the following:

> The conditional probability density function of $Y$ given the
>   occurrence of the value $x$ of $X$ is given by  $$ f_{Y}(y|X=x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} $$

It is my understanding that this is the same as 
$$ f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}, $$
another common form with a slight notational difference.

With this in mind, is the conditional density function a function of two variables? Everywhere I look seems to define the conditional density only as a function of $y$. I understand that $Y$ is being conditioned on a given value of $X$, but the value that $X$ takes on is still represented by a variable $x$. This would lead me to believe that both variables ($x$ and $y$) must be accounted for by the function, implying $f_{Y|X}(y|x): \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto [0,\infty)$, not $f_{Y|X}(y|x): \mathbb{R} \mapsto [0,\infty)$.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the scope of the definition. If someone could point me in the right direction here I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of $X=x$ is known, and can be interpreted as a "parameter" (in a functional sense). It gives different parametrizations of the functions, and indeed when one talks of $f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x)$ one generally refers to a *family* of conditional distributions (one for every value in the support of $X$). However, one must not forget that every member of this family is parametrized by a *known* value of $X$. Therefore, for density purposes, $f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x)$ is a function only of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it helps clear things up. A quick followup: so when I see $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$, is it correct to say that it's not _really_ a probability density, but more like a family of distributions (as you mentioned)? Or do I need to think about it as a density, and simply throw out the idea of $x$ (the value $X$ takes on) varying at all? Or perhaps both of these things; for whatever reason there's something unsatisfactory about it that I can't quite put my finger on.

Comment: Your inquiry is good. I will edit the post tomorrow to clear things up ultimately.